# react-pdf throwing Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-pdf

I'm implementing react-pdf to show a pdf within a web view. The react app works with Typescript and Next if that helps in any way.

So far, this is my code

```
const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
// some code here
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (numPages:any) =>  {
      setNumPages(numPages);
    }
  return (
    <>
          <div className="white-background">
            <hr />
            <div className="pdf-container">
              <Document
                file={data?.pdf}
                options={{ workerSrc: "/pdf.worker.js" }}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
              >
                {Array.from(new Array(numPages), (el, index) => (
                  <Page key={`page_${index + 1}`} pageNumber={index + 1} />
                ))}
              </Document>
              <p>
                Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
              </p>
            </div>
            
          <hr/>
          </div>

   </>
```

As far as I'm concerned, I used the component the same way as the documentation, but it is throwing this error ->

> Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

pointing to `const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);`
especifically to `useState(null)`

I strongly believe that the problem comes from calling `onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}` as the function is calling the reference to the hook and whenever it returns it loads an extra hook within page, which throws the error.

The problem then is that `onLoadSuccess` is expecting a reference and not a function

I already tried passing with parenthesis () but it throws an error. So no clue so far.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was placing

`const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);`

after a conditional in my Function Component. I placed it at the top and the problem was fixed.